# Sequelize(v5) freezableTableName:true not working in Migration code

Tags: sequelize.js

```
Even if i use FreezableTableName:True it stores table in DB with Plural one.
```

### How could i solve this problem in sequelize Migaration latest code i.e,sequelize latest version(v5) and node latest 10.x

```
//user.js
-------------------
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const user = sequelize.define('user', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.TEXT
    }, {});
    user.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
    };
    return user;
};

//migration file xxxxxxx-create-user.js
----------------------------------
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            email: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            password: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            }
        });
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
    }
};
```

it adds plural table name in DB,how to avoid that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one that actually creates your table is your migration code.

```
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        // you're specifying `users` instead of `user` here
        return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
```

So please replace `users` with `user` first.

And in order for your sequelize models to know where to look up when searching for table `user` you have to finish one more extra step.

```
const user = sequelize.define('user', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.TEXT
}, { tableName: 'user' }); // pass table name option here
```

Now you'll be able to do your query again.

Comment: it's working fine,Thanks!!.but at the same time if i want to make timeStamps:false where should add (globally not for individual model t)

Comment: just make your `option` in model as `{ tableName: 'user', timestamps: false }`

Comment: but i think i need to remove the feilds in the migration file before adding that timestamps:false in model file.